# HW Accel Transcode Intel Quick Sync Video QSV h264_qsv and CRF Quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having a problem with HW Accel **Intel Quick Sync Video** and **CRF**.

It looks like **CRF** `-crf` is not compatible with `-c:v h264_qsv`.

Only **Bit Rate** `-b:v` works with `-c:v h264_qsv`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -crf 25 -pix_fmt nv12 output.mkv
```

---

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync

The guide says "ICQ mode (which is similar to crf mode of x264)" `-global_quality 25`

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -global_quality 25 -pix_fmt nv12 output.mkv
```

But I cannot get it to work. I get the error `Selected ratecontrol mode is unsupported`.

---

How do I get either CRF or ICQ to work?

Answer (score 1):

seems like the cpu generation matters

i've recently tried `-global_quality` on 3 computers with sandy bridge, ivy bridge and haswell on board

both sandy and ivy bridge cpu qsv gave error

only haswell accepted this option and did the job